# Spark installation seems ok but when running program I'm having issues with environment variables. Is this .bash_profile correct?

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I installed Spark following these instructions : https://gist.github.com/ololobus/4c221a0891775eaa86b0
and running a simple script from jupyter-notebook (OS X)

First I call the spark as follows:

In:

```
import os
execfile(os.path.join(os.environ["SPARK_HOME"], 'python/pyspark/shell.py'))
```

Out:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.2
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.12 (default, Jul  2 2016 17:43:17)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

Which seems to behave correctly. I then check that the spark context exists

In:

```
sc
```

Out:

```
<pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x107156a50>
```

I import a dataset, and want to print 100 samples, just to check that it's working:

In:

```
distFile = sc.textFile("track2/training.txt")
print distFile.take(100)
```

And here I get this awful looking error.

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ca0a9eec5d5b> in <module>()
----> 1 print distFile.take(100)

/Users/elya/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
   1308 
   1309             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1310             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1311 
   1312             items += res

/Users/elya/spark/python/pyspark/context.pyc in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    931         # SparkContext#runJob.
    932         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 933         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    934         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    935 

/Users/elya/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/Users/elya/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/Users/elya/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11, localhost): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/elya/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip:/Users/elya/spark/python:/Users/elya/spark/python/build:/Users/elya/spark/python:/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/elya/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip:/Users/elya/spark/python:/Users/elya/spark/python/build:/Users/elya/spark/python:/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 14 more
```

The crux of it seems to be the following:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 11, localhost): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/elya/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip:/Users/elya/spark/python:/Users/elya/spark/python/build:/Users/elya/spark/python:/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've gone through a couple installations already and keep having issues with the environment variables. Here's .bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/elya/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export SPARK_HOME=/Users/elya/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/elya/spark/bin
# export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
# export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$PYTHONPATH/bin/python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/elya/spark/python

# Hadoop home directory configuration
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

# For Apache Spark
if which java > /dev/null; then export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home); fi

# For a ipython notebook and pyspark integration
if which pyspark > /dev/null; then
  export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/"
  export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
  export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
fi
```

I'm not very familiar with how these work and am afraid to take things out and mess it up even more. Can any of you point me to what I'm doing wrong?
I appreciate any help with this

Comment: At first glance, `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/elya/spark/bin` does not point to the Python executable, but to a directory. Same goes for `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/elya/spark/python`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 import os
 import sys

 os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/"

 sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python")
 sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/apache-
 spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip")
 sc.stop()
 try:
     from pyspark import SparkContext
     from pyspark import SparkConf

 except ImportError as e:
     print ("error importing spark modules", e)
     sys.exit(1)

sc = SparkContext('local[*]','PySpark')
```

Here I used my own file path and was able to print the lines

```
distFile = sc.textFile("track2/training.txt")
print distFile.take(100)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I didn't realize you had answered. Unfortunately this didn't solve it.Here is the main part of the error I get:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o222.csv.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at: