# PySpark run locally on Mac: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin"

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting this error running locally in pyCharm and tried all options:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

./bash_profile:
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/:/usr/local/lib/python3.9:$PYTHONP$
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PATH
#export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH

ls -lrt /usr/local/opt/apache-spark:

```
/usr/local/opt/apache-spark -> ../Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1
```

Python Interpretor in PyCharm:
/usr/local/bin/python3

In my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #import os
    #import sys
    #os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/"
    #sys.path.append("/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python")
    #sys.path.append("/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip")
    #findspark.init()
    #conf = SparkConf()
    #conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:///")
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("SyslogMaskUtility").getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    #sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    rdd_raw = sc.textFile('/Users/abcd/PycharmProjects/SyslogToJson/SyslogParser/syslog_event.txt')
    print(rdd_raw.count())
    spark.stop()
```

I followed:
https://medium.com/beeranddiapers/installing-apache-spark-on-mac-os-ce416007d79f

and referred:
[Spark installation seems ok but when running program I'm having issues with environment variables. Is this .bash_profile correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708939/spark-installation-seems-ok-but-when-running-program-im-having-issues-with-envi)

All directories and files under /usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/ have all permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx   13 abcd  admin   416 Oct 29 17:34 bin
```

Any help please since I am struggling with this.
The same code works when I run from the pyspark command line.

Thanks.

Comment: Try installing Spark without homebrew

Comment: Okay. I will follow this: https://medium.com/luckspark/installing-spark-2-3-0-on-macos-high-sierra-276a127b8b85

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, I install Spark and Hadoop separately

```
# install PySpark
pip3 install pyspark

# download and extract Hadoop 3.2.2
wget https://downloads.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.2.2/hadoop-3.2.2.tar.gz
unzip hadoop-3.2.2.tar.gz

# setup environment variables
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/'
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"

# run Python
python3
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import types as T

spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .master('local[*]')
    .appName('SO')
    .getOrCreate()
)
# <pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x10f9e7220>
```

Comment: I ran thru the steps as above. From the terminal I am able to run but from PyCharm I get the same error - Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachiexport SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/Users/rm185431/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/:/usr/local/lib/python3.9:$PYTHONP$
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH

Comment: The above are the path I have added to my .bash_profile

Comment: Environment variable in Edit configuration has: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin;PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin;PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/